# Implementing a swiping tab view without using Android support v4 package

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

Now I am developing a SDK project, the SDK will provide a Activity with swiping tab view, the easiest way is to use Viewpager, however, since I do not want to force the SDK's users to include support v4 package, I am finding some way to implement it without using Viewpager.

I already looked the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523871/android-swipe-view-with-tabs-without-using-the-v4-support-library), but I am not plan to include all the source code of viewpager in my project.

Any solution or open source library is appreciated, Thank you.